# How to use different versions of Eclipse in the same project and the same source base

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I work on a multi-platform software that works on Windows, Linux and VxWorks.
The software is written en C and C++, and we use :

- For the Linux target and our main development environment, we use **Eclipse 3.7.2 + CDT plugins** (the one that comes with Ubuntu 12.04).
- For the VxWorks target, we use Wind River Workbench, a Windows, **Eclipse 3.7.1 CDT-based program provided by Wind River**, the makers of VxWorks.
- For the Windows target, we use Visual Studio.

My issue is that both the Linux Eclipse and Wind River Workbench creates .project and .cproject files in the root directory of a project. Since the project directories are shared accross platforms, there is a conflict.

The only workaround I found was the following :

```
/.../mysoftware/others/src ---> contains the code
/.../mysoftware/others/inc ---> contains the code
/.../mysoftware/others     ---> where the Wind River Workbench ".something" files are
/.../mysoftware/linux/src  ---> symlink to ../others/src
/.../mysoftware/linux/inc  ---> symlink to ../others/inc
/.../mysoftware/linux      ---> where the Linux Eclipse ".something" files are
```

This solution is quite ugly and makes the Eclipse plugin for my SCM (Mercurial) stop working, and only works for Linux.

How can I make multiple Eclipse-based IDE use their own set of ".something" files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you don't check those files into SCM, and add them to Mercurial's ignore list.

You can have template versions of those files checked in (`.project.linux`, `.project.vxworks` etc.) that each developer can copy by hand to `.project` after checking out the project from Mercurial. This is adequate as long as they don't change too much.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I stored on .project.vx and one .project.vxworks for each project. Instead of making a copy by hand, I made a script that created symlinks (we have more than 50 projects) from .project.linux to .project. I even discovered the Windows command "mklink".

Comment: @redmatt glad you got it working. `mklink` is an underused classic all right.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use one original folder for source control operations and 2 different folders for each platform.

You should replicate checkout folder structure using symbolic links in each folder.
Then, create desired CDT project in each folder. Eclipse project files will go in that folders rather than original folders so they won't conflict.